# What is difference between sshcode and VS Code Remote Development Extension

Tags: compare, vscode-remote

I really love the concept that I can write codes by using my laptop but all the hard things will run in the server.

So I did some research and found 2 solutions:

1. sshcode which introduce by Coder Technologies Inc. (https://github.com/cdr/sshcode)
2. VS Code Remote Development Extension (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release)

In my short time, I guess 2 solutions are the same.

But if you got the deeper understanding, please give me some comparison so I can have right decision for which case I should use sshcode and some other cases I should use VS Code Remote Development Extension.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unforunately the developers of **sshcode** [deprecated it and stopped maintenance](https://github.com/cdr/sshcode/issues/185), in favour of another of their open source projects, **code-server** https://github.com/cdr/code-server

So I will compare those two.

The first, Microsoft VS Code Remote Development Extensions, connects your local VS Code to a remote instance of VS Code, running on your development server.  (During its short life, sshcode also did this.)

The second, code-server, connects your local web browser to a remote instance of VS Code.

Answer (score -2):

**`Question`**

```
 1. I have VS Code installed in my local machine.
 2. I have a remote machine where I have some docker container running.
 3. I am able to remote ssh into this machine from VS.
 4. I am able to using Remote Development to use VS Code to run and build code locally.
```

**`Requirement`**

```
Can I use the feature in a way such that I can directly get inside container in the remote instance and start developing my code in there using VS Code feature like when I reopen the folder in container instead of opening it on local machine, it needs to open in the container that is running inside the instance.
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, as both extensions work this way.